# Get Yesterday's date in mysql with different time

Tags: mysql

I have problem i want to fetch yesterday's date data from mysql table.Which i try below query.

```
select id FROM booking_assigned ba WHERE ba.is_checkout = '1' AND ba.checkout_date = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

But in checkout_date columun value is as 2015-04-14 16:26:08.So, that's why above query return zero result

Actually I want result from this query.

I didn't get any result,And also every time checkout_date time is different.

Comment: Any idea where I did mistake?

Comment: What is the type of `checkout_date`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert checkout_date from DATETIME to DATE.

```
select id FROM booking_assigned ba WHERE ba.is_checkout = '1' AND DATE(ba.checkout_date) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the datetime value to date using `date` function as

```
AND date(ba.checkout_date)
```